# Chilkat json outputs decimal numbers with comma

Tags: json, visual-foxpro, chilkat

In chilkat activeX (my version: 9.5.0.86), when I create object with numeric property .emit() method returns JSON string with number where decimal part is separated with comma. This depends on my regional settings
[here in Control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtKpL.jpg). But this shouldn't be dependent on this, because this JSON RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt says that numbers must always be separated by dot.

This code (in VFP)

```
oJson = CreateObject('Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject')
oJson.AddNumberAt(-1,"test1", 12.3)
?oJson.Emit()
```

when I have set comma in settings, output of this code is:
{"test1":12,3}

and when I have set dot, output is:
{"test1":12.3}

Is there a way how to setup chilkat, to always get numbers with dot?
It seems, that problem is with method AddNumberAt, because when I get json with load method

Comment: Maybe do not use chilkat then? There are JSON libraries like nfJon (https://github.com/VFPX/nfJson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd argument to UpdateNumber should be a string.
See https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatJsonObjectRef.html#method81

You passed a floating point number, which was coerced into a string by your programming language, and the coercion is what caused the comma to be used.

Comment: why would a coercion cause comma to be used? How it is dependent on the programming language it is used. Where did you see the programming language forcing a comma? Documentation says "AddNumberAt(ByVal index As Long, name As String, numericStr As String) As Long" which is rather weird to use a string for a numeric.